# Ending while loop with string not working

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a problem with trying to end this while loop.  When it runs, typing "exit" for the name part doesn't seem to register and the code continues as if "exit" was a name typed in. What I intended to happen is for "exit" to be typed in so that the loop can end. Any help?  Here is the code for the class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class BankTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<BankAccount> bank = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //enter into list the accounts and end with exit typed in
        String name = "";
        while (name.contains("exit")==false) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the name(exit to stop): ");
            name = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the deposit: ");
            double balance = scan.nextDouble();
            scan.nextLine();
            BankAccount newAccount = new BankAccount(name, balance);
            bank.add(newAccount);
        }
        //find highest account amount
        double largestMon = bank.get(0).getBalance();
        String largestPer = bank.get(0).getName();
        for (int i=0;i<bank.size();i++) {
            double compare = bank.get(i).getBalance();
            if (compare>largestMon) {
                largestMon = compare;
                largestPer = bank.get(i).getName();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(largestPer+" has the largest account with $");
    }
}
```

I've already tried switching between != and equals() compare the strings.

Comment: You read `name` at the top of your loop and don't check if it is "exit" until the top of the next iteration.

Comment: You can change <br>
`name.contains("exit")==false`<br>
into <br>
`!name.contains("exit")` <br>

Answer (score 1):

Change `while (name.contains("exit")==false)` to `while(true)`

and add line `if (name.equals('exit')) break;` after `name = scan.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could change
`name.contains("exit")==false`into `!name.contains("exit")`

 A better solution would be to use a while true loop and break if the name variable is equal to "exit"

```
while (true) {
   System.out.println("Please enter the name(exit to stop): ");
   name = scan.nextLine();
   if(name.equals("exit"))
      break;
```

Notice that in cases like this you shouldn't use `.contains()` or `.equals` but rather `.equalsIgnoreCase()`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
while(true){
        System.out.println("Please enter the name(exit to stop): ");
        name = scan.nextLine();

        if(name.equals("exit"))
            break;

        System.out.println("Please enter the deposit: ");
        double balance = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();
        BankAccount newAccount = new BankAccount(name, balance);
        bank.add(newAccount);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Modify your while loop as follows:

```
                while (true) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the name(exit to stop): ");
                name = scan.nextLine();
                if(name.equals("exit"))
                break;
                System.out.println("Please enter the deposit: ");
                double balance = scan.nextDouble();
                scan.nextLine();
                BankAccount newAccount = new BankAccount(name, balance);
                bank.add(newAccount);
            }
```